# How to select Max of each row?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using Postgres SQL and I would like to return the rows which has the greatest seq number.

Eg:

```
row_name, seq, data
row1, 1, abc
row1, 2, def
row2, 1, hij
row2, 2, klm
row2, 3, nop
```

I want the result to be :

```
row1, 2, def
row2, 3, nop
```

I am using:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name where seq = (SELECT MAX(seq) from table_name)
```

but it is returning only row2, 3, nop.

Please help thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `subquery` then inner join the `max(seq).`

```
select * from table_name t
inner join 
    (select max(seq) seq, row_name from table_name group by row_name) t1 on t1.row_name = t.row_name and t.seq = t1.seq
```

Comment: Hi! what is "t" in t.row_name?

Comment: @AlanTT, updated, `t` is the alias of the first table

Comment: How can I implement this in HQL? Because HQL cannot allow sub queries in FROM.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use ROW_NUMBER for getting your desired output as below-

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=db4059fdab89d4913792f707b907ecf1)

```
SELECT row_name, seq, data 
FROM 
(
    SELECT *, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY row_name ORDER BY seq DESC) RN
    FROM your_table
)A
WHERE RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT 
    row_name, seq, data
FROM (
  SELECT 
    row_name, seq,  data, 
    max( seq) over(partition by row_name) max_seq 
  FROM your_table
) S
where seq=max_seq
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically the most efficient solution in Postgres for this type of problems is to use `distinct on ()`

```
select distinct on (row_name) row_name, seq, data
from the_table
order by row_name, seq desc;
```

Answer (score -1):

we can use do it by descending  order by too.

```
 SELECT *FROM table_name ORDER BY column1, column2 DESC
```