# How to convert SQL subquery to HQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, hibernate, hql

I have asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59168686/how-to-select-max-of-each-row)

The solution is :

```
select * from table_name t
inner join 
    (select max(seq) seq, row_name from table_name group by row_name) t1 on t1.row_name = t.row_name and t.seq = t1.seq
```

But I need to convert it to HQL. The solution uses a subquery in FROM which is not allowed in HQL.

How can I convert the subquery to HQL using SELECT or WHERE?

Thanks.

Comment: yo can't have this syntax on HQL , you can add a view for your subquery and then map it on a model then join it in your query .

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goal through [Hibernate Native Query](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#sql-jpa-query), see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33237430/7765316)

Try this

```
List<Object[]> objects = session.createNativeQuery(
                "select * from table_name t"
                + "inner join"
                + "(select max(seq) seq, row_name from table_name group by row_name) t1"
                + "on t1.row_name = t.row_name and t.seq = t1.seq")
.list();
```

This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30382629/7765316) shows using subquery in HQL through native query